# How to rotate 3D Scatterplot

Tags: r, 3d, rotation, scatter-plot

Below is a code that works using the scatterplot3d() function to run a 3D scatterplot of height vs weight vs volume where points are a Class value between 1-6. The angle is currently at 45 degrees and I know I can tilt the plot by changing the angle. What code do I use to rotate the plot to the left or right so that I can provide multiple views of the plot?

```
df
#    Class   height     weight    volume
# 1    4     0.83         0.85      0.83
# 2    2     0.75         0.80      0.76
# 3    3     0.75         0.80      0.84
# 4    5     0.52         0.59      1
# 5    6     0.52         0.59      0.99

 color <- c(rgb(0.68, 0.93, 0.96), rgb(0, 0.74, 0.92), rgb(0.68, 0.86, 0.49), rgb(1, 0.8, 0.3), 
 rgb(1, 0, 0))
 scatterplot3d(x=c(0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0), y=c(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0), z=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), box=T, type='l', 
 color='grey', grid=F, lwd=2, xlab='height', ylab='', zlab='volume', xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), 
 zlim=c(0,1), angle=45)
 text(7, 0, 'weight', srt=45)
 par(new=T)

 scatterplot3d(x=c(0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0), y=c(0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5), z=rep(0,5), box=F, type='l', 
 color='grey', grid=F, lwd=2,xlab='', ylab='', zlab='', xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), zlim=c(0,1), 
 axis=F, angle=45)
 par(new=T)

 scatterplot3d(x=c(0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5), y=c(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0), z=rep(0,5), box=F, type='l', 
 color='grey', grid=F, lwd=2,
          xlab='', ylab='', zlab='', xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), zlim=c(0,1), axis=F, angle=45)
 par(new=T)

 scatterplot3d(x=c(0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5), y=c(0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5), z=rep(0,5), box=F, type='l', 
 color='grey', grid=F, lwd=2,
          xlab='', ylab='', zlab='', xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), zlim=c(0,1), axis=F, angle=45)
 par(new=T)

 for (i in 6:2) {

 scatterplot3d(height[Class==i], weight[Class==i], volume[Class==i], box=F, pch=c(2,1,0,1,20)[i-1], 
 color=color[i-1], grid=F,
            xlab='', ylab='', zlab='', xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), zlim=c(0, 1), axis=F, angle=45)
 par(new=T)
 }
 legend(0.2, 4.7, legend=c(paste('Level', 2:6)), pch=c(2,1,0,1,19), col=color, title='Class', 
 cex=0.70)
```

Comment: The `angle=` argument does rotate the plot. Try 45, 135, 225, and 315 to see the difference. You cannot put the x=0, y=0 at the back of the plot but you can rotate from left to right through 180 degrees.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and apologies for only responding now, I didn't have access to R to try it out until now. I've been playing around with the various angles as you suggested but the plot becomes completely distorted.  Should I be changing the angle for every "angle=" in the code or just part of it? You mentioned I cannot put the x=0, y=0 at the back of the plot, must I change the code and if so I'm unsure what i must change it to? Your advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. Your code makes the same plot 4 times. If you change the angle on each of those plots you will get 4 different views of he same data. If that is not what you are trying to do, you will have to be more specific.

Comment: Hi, all this code produces one plot only. The first few sections of code that starts with scatterplot3d( ) is to generate the axes and 4 grey quadrants on the base/floor of the cube. The last piece of code that starts with scatterplot3d() brings the points into the scatterplot. If I replace all  "angle=45" with "angle=225" it becomes distorted. Perhaps there's another line of code that needs to be added that will turn the plot to the left or right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two views of your data. You should always use `dput()` to paste your data into a question so we can access it easily:

```
dfa <- structure(list(Class = c(4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L), height = c(0.83, 
     0.75, 0.75, 0.52, 0.52), weight = c(0.85, 0.8, 0.8, 0.59, 0.59),
     volume = c(0.83, 0.76, 0.84, 1, 0.99)), class = "data.frame",
     row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

We can greatly simplify your code by using the functions that `scatterplot3d` returns as follows:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
color <- c(rgb(0.68, 0.93, 0.96), rgb(0, 0.74, 0.92), rgb(0.68, 0.86, 0.49),
     rgb(1, 0.8, 0.3), rgb(1, 0, 0))
plt <- with(dfa, scatterplot3d(height, weight, volume, xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1),
     zlim=c(0, 1), ylab="", color=color, pch=c(2, 1, 0, 1, 20), grid=FALSE,
     scale.y=1, angle=45))
plt$points3d(x=c(0, 1), y=c(0.5, 0.5), z=c(0, 0), type="l", col="grey")
plt$points3d(x=c(0.5, 0.5), y=c(0, 1), z=c(0, 0), type="l", col="grey")
xy <- unlist(plt$xyz.convert(1.25, .5, 0))
text(xy[1], xy[2], "weight", srt=45, pos=2)
legend(0.2, 4.7, legend=c(paste('Level', 2:6)), pch=c(2,1,0,1,19), col=color,
     title='Class', cex=0.70)
```

[image: Plot 1]

Notice we estimate the position of the y-axis label and use a function to convert the 3d coordinates into 2d for plotting. Now we'll do a 135 degree rotation:

```
plt <- with(dfa, scatterplot3d(height, weight, volume, xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1),
     zlim=c(0, 1), ylab="", color=color, pch=c(2, 1, 0, 1, 20), grid=FALSE,
     scale.y=.75, angle=135))
plt$points3d(x=c(0, 1), y=c(0.5, 0.5), z=c(0, 0), type="l", col="grey")
plt$points3d(x=c(0.5, 0.5), y=c(0, 1), z=c(0, 0), type="l", col="grey")
xy <- unlist(plt$xyz.convert(-0.2, .5, 0))
text(xy[1], xy[2], "weight", srt=-45, pos=4)
legend(0.2, 4.7, legend=c(paste('Level', 2:6)), pch=c(2,1,0,1,19), col=color,
     title='Class', cex=0.70)
```

[image: Plot 2]

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much for taking the time to write this. One last question regarding the "pos=". If I wanted to do a 225 degree rotation, I would write srt=-45  but I'm unsure what the number would be for "pos= ".  I'm unsure  how the numbering for "pos=" applies in terms of the degree of rotation?

Comment: It is a bit of trial and error. The default (0) centers the text directly on the point. Then pos=1 is below the center, 2 is left of center, 3 is above center, and 4 is right of center.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! Much appreciated.