# Rotate scatterplot3d around X axis

Tags: r, 3d, scatter-plot, scatterplot3d

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796107/how-to-rotate-3d-scatterplot) where dcarlsen helpfully explains how to rotate a 3dscatterplot around the z-axis in r.  However, I would also like to rotate around the x axis.  Code:

```
attach(dataset)
dateconverted <- as.Date(Date)
Status_converted <- as.factor(Vaccine_status)
age <- as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", Declared_age))
scatterplot3d(dateconverted[4500:5115], age[4500:5115], New_cases[4500:5115], color=c("red","blue","green")[Status_converted[4500:5115]], pch=19, angle=75)
```

It gives something along the lines of:

[image: Graph]

Obviously there's tons of work to be done on the graph but I'd like to rotate the front upwards (around the x-axis).

Comment: Please include some sample data so your example is reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

You can try other libraries that generate even more dynamic graphics, an example of which you can see here:

```
library(rgl)
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
library(rglwidge)

plot3d(
  mtcars$wt,
  mtcars$disp,
  mtcars$mpg,
  type = "s",
  size = 1,
  lit = TRUE,
  main = "Car Weight Vs Engine Displacement Vs Mileage",
  sub = "3-D Plot"
)
```